# Find the value of the following summation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

> If $$f(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{20}\binom{20}{r}\big(\ln(1+x)\big)^r$$
>   Find
>   $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \bigg(h(x^{2^r})-1\bigg)$$
>   where, $h(x) = \big(f(x)\big)^{1/20}$

**My Attempt:**

$f(x)$ is the binomial expansion of $(1+\ln(1+x))^{20}$.

Then, $h(x) = 1+\ln(1+x)$

Plugging this into the summation, I get

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \ln(1+x^{2^r})$$

I am unable to go any further. How do you find this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

For

$1-x\ne0,$

$$(1-x)\prod_{r=0}^n(1+x^{2^r})=1-x^{2^{n+1}}$$

As $\ln(1+x)$ is defined in $(-1,+1]$

we need to consider $x=1$ separately

Otherwise for $|x|<1,$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{2^{n+1}}=?$$