# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n} \left(1+\frac{2}{45^{2^k}+45^{-2^k}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, telescopic-series

Evaluate $$P=\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n} \left(1+\frac{2}{45^{2^k}+45^{-2^k}}\right)$$

My try:

Let $a_k=45^{2^k}$ Then we have $45^{-2^k}=\frac{1}{a_k}$

So We get:

$$1+\frac{2}{a_k+\frac{1}{a_k}}=\frac{(a_k+1)^2}{a_k^2+1}$$

So

$$P=\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{(a_k+1)^2}{a_k^2+1}$$

Any way from here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that

Hint:

$$(a_k+1)(a_k-1)=(45^{2^k})^2-1=a_{k+1}-1$$

$$(a_0+1)\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k+1)=a_{n+1}-1$$

Similarly, $$(a_0^2+1)\prod_{k=1}^n(a_k^2+1)=a_{n+1}^2-1$$

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628850/find-the-value-of-the-following-summation  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621877/infinite-summation-involving-exponents

Comment: Typing too slow . . .

Comment: @richrow, suggest you not to purvey the whole solution allowing some thought from the OP

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a_k^2=a_{k+1}$, so 
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(a_k+1)^2}{a_k^2+1}=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(a_k+1)^2}{a_{k+1}+1}
=\frac{a_0+1}{a_{n+1}+1}\cdot(a_0+1)(a_1+1)\ldots(a_n+1).
$$
Then, 
$$
a_k+1=\frac{a_k^2-1}{a_k-1}=\frac{a_{k+1}-1}{a_k-1},~\text{so}~
$$
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(a_k+1)^2}{a_k^2+1}=\frac{a_0+1}{a_{n+1}+1}\cdot(a_0+1)(a_1+1)\ldots(a_n+1)=\frac{a_0+1}{a_{n+1}+1}\cdot\frac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_0-1}.
$$
Since $a_{n+1}\rightarrow +\infty$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$ we have 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(a_k+1)^2}{a_k^2+1}=\frac{a_0+1}{a_0-1}=\frac{45+1}{45-1}=\frac{23}{22}.
$$

Comment: your last step is a typo...you interchanged numerator and denominator

Comment: Indeed, edited.